# Question on JK Flip flop Output waveforms

Tags: flipflop, logic-gates

I'm fairly new to the world of Flip Flops, and this type of material. I'm hoping to gain some clarification on how to correctly create output waveforms based on different implementation. I'm not exactly sure how the implementation of a JK affects how the output would be calculated.

[image: JK Flip Flop Implementations]

Please note I'm not asking you do answer this question for me. Rather, I'm hoping that somebody will be able to offer some guidance about how I can calculate/draw what the output should be.

Thanks!

Comment: the output depends upon the level of the J and K inputs at the time of the clock pulse. Try this tutorial : http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_2.html

Comment: You need to know if the device is positive or negative edge triggered. This means does it trigger on an up-going clock edge or a donw-going clock edge.

Comment: @jippie so the second one (JK w/+ve-DFF) would be a positive edge and would trigger when it's an up-going clock edge?

Comment: I was only typing about the clock. Which edge will be used by the device to clock it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Deciding the output waveform you choose one of the two case:

1. **J-k flip is +ve/-ve edge triggered.**

If it is +ve edge triggered then calculate output at +ve edge(rising edge) of clock pulse. This value will hold til the next +ve edge.
If -ve edge triggered then follw the same at -ve edge.

**2. If J-k flip flop is not edge-triggered**

- clock= High :  Draw output correspoding the truth table.
- clock= Low  :  It'll hold the previous output.

In above case you can simply find out the uotput using the truth table of j-k flip-flop.
[image]

Comment: This makes sense. 

In the first case (edge triggered), would you use the same truth table as 2, except you calculate at either the rising or falling edge?

Comment: Yeah, just calculate output at edge using same truth table and this output will remain same untill next edge no matter what are your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excerpt from a Texas Instruments data sheet.

The J and K inputs must be stable some time before the clock goes low, and here's the full [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc73.pdf) for your perusal.

[image]